# Replacing Unicode character codes with characters in String in Java

Tags: java, string, unicode

I have a Java String like this: "peque\u00f1o".  Note that it has an embedded Unicode character: '\u00f1'.

Is there a method in Java that will replace these Unicode character sequences with the actual characters?  That is, a method that would return "pequeño" if you gave it "peque\u00f1o" as input?

Note that I have a string that has 12 chars (those that we see, that happen to be in the ASCII range).

Comment: `a Java String like this "peque\u00f1o"` It's not clear if you have a string that have 12 chars (those that we see, that happen to be in the ascii range) or a Java string that was initialized with that literal (source code) (7 unicode chars).

Comment: In the first case, sorin's answer (StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava) applies. In the second, Howard's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember giving the same response last week, use `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils`.

Comment: Oh - I might have misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Dilum: the question is ambiguous, indeed.

Answer (score 5):

Actually the string is "pequeño".

```
String s = "peque\u00f1o";
System.out.println(s.length());
System.out.println(s);
```

yields

```
7
pequeño
```

i.e. seven chars and the correct representation on `System.out`.

Comment: +1 further: try `System.out.println("peque\u00f1o".equals("pequeño"));`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the appropriate fonts, a `println` or setting the string in a JLabel or JTextArea should do the trick. The escaping is only for the compiler.

If you plan to copy-paste the readable strings in source, remember to also choose a suitable file encoding like UTF8.