# Replace unicode characters?

Tags: java, android, unicode, webview, textview

I'm trying to show some html text in textview extracted from webview. The returned string contains some unicode characters which I'm not able to replace. 
I created a class to replace these characters but it's not working

```
public class Localizer {

    String message;

    public Localizer(String message){
        this.message=message;
    }

    public String Localize(){

        message = message.replaceAll("\\u0103","&#259;").replaceAll("\\u00EE","&#238;").replaceAll("\\u0163","&#355;").replaceAll("\\u015F","&#351;").replaceAll("\\u00E2","&#226;").replaceAll("\\u00CE","&#206;").replaceAll("\\u0102","&#258;");
        return message;
    }
}
```

and when I'm calling it, I use

```
tvResultat.setText(new Localizer(Html.fromHtml(message)).Localize());
```

the output is still whit Unicode. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please check this ans https://stackoverflow.com/a/6350124/4448617

Answer (score 0):

solution would be just to keep ASCII symbols with such regexp

```
message = message.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/g, "");
```